# Joining vector elements by row, converting vector rows to strings

Tags: r

Is there a "by row" operation in R to convert each row in a vector like this to strings?

```
> d= cbind("Data", c("2", "73"))
> d
     [,1]   [,2]
[1,] "Data" "2" 
[2,] "Data" "73"
```

What I want is to get strings like

```
     [,1]
[1,] "Data 2"
[2,] "Data 73"
```

Is there an easy way to join items by row?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, there is. It is called "apply" ;-)

```
apply(d,1,paste,collapse=" ")
[1] "Data 2"  "Data 73"
# convert to matrix using as.matrix to get exactly your solution
```

See `?apply` and `?paste`

Comment: blarg, of course, the apply, duh :( But the paste, collapse= " " part I would never have figured out, thanks :)

Comment: @gakera: Figuring out the `collapse=" "` part is pretty easy if you read the documentation `?paste`.

Comment: The help doesn't include any examples of collapse=" " usage, at least not in my version. But from the text it's kinda clear what it does, once you see it in all the noise.

Comment: @gakera: tss tss tss... it's not noise, it's very valuable information actually. At a certain point you'll be more than happy with the "noise".

Comment: Hehe, I like how quick people are to defend the R Help, it's like it's everybody's baby. Very good, I appreciate all the help I can get. And yes, SO has a very good reputation of being a good place to get a quick answer, and delivers usually without fail. I'm not ashamed of being a little lazy when it comes to this kind of stuff. I leave it to you to define what "little" means, I'm sure you'll enjoy it.

Answer (score 5):

A general way to do it without resorting to `?apply`:

```
do.call(paste, as.data.frame(d))
[1] "Data 2"  "Data 73"
```

Where `as.data.frame` is used to avoid subscripts.

Edit:

`do.call` is a function which takes another function as first argument, and a list as second argument. It is often used to send lists of arguments to functions (in our case, the columns of `d` to `paste()`). We send d as a data.frame (a type of list) for this trick to work.

Comment: That's true. The efficiency gain would be greater if the data was already a data.frame, but the `apply()` solution is far faster for vectors. The advantage in this one is that one need not limit oneself to a single data type when applying paste, but there are also a lot of disadvantages: for example, pasting by rows instead of columns only requires a number change in the `apply()` solution, whereas this one requires major code changes. Overall, this solution is only for my typical use cases, where I did an index with `expand.grid()` and concatenate these with `do.call(paste)`

Answer (score 4):

After a quick glace at `?paste`, it's clear that `apply` isn't needed for the example given.  It would be handy if there are several columns though.

```
> paste(d[,1],d[,2])
[1] "Data 2"  "Data 73"
```

Comment: But I need a general way that works without specifying the rows explicitly. I'm sorry I wasn't clear enough about that, but the apply method works very well for what I need to do.