# str_extract_all: return all patterns found in string concatenated as vector

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I want to extract everything but a pattern and return this concetenated in a string.

I tried to combine str_extract_all together with sapply and cat

```
x = c("a_1","a_20","a_40","a_30","a_28")
data <- tibble(age = x)


# extracting just the first pattern is easy
data %>% 
  mutate(age_new = str_extract(age,"[^a_]"))
# combining str_extract_all and sapply doesnt work
data %>% 
  mutate(age_new = sapply(str_extract_all(x,"[^a_]"),function(x) cat(x,sep="")))


class(str_extract_all(x,"[^a_]"))
sapply(str_extract_all(x,"[^a_]"),function(x) cat(x,sep=""))
```

Returns NULL instead of concatenated patterns

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of `cat`, we can use `paste`.  Also, with `tidyverse`, can make use of `map` and `str_c` (in place of `paste` - from `stringr`)

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  mutate(age_new = map_chr(str_extract_all(x, "[^a_]+"), ~ str_c(.x, collapse="")))
```

---

using `OP's code

```
data %>%
    mutate(age_new = sapply(str_extract_all(x,"[^a_]"),
               function(x) paste(x,collapse="")))
```

---

If the intention is to get the numbers

```
library(readr)
data %>%
     mutate(age_new = parse_number(x))
```

Comment: You could also avoid `map_chr` in your first solution and use: `str_extract_all(x, "[^a_]+", simplify = T)[,1]`

Comment: The tidyverse answer seems better than the apply solution because it doesn't treat empty results as results when you concatenate

Answer (score 2):

Here is a non tidyverse solution, just using stringr.

```
apply(str_extract_all(column,regex_command,simplify = TRUE),1,paste,collapse="")
```

'simplify' = TRUE changed str_extract_all to output a matrix, and apply iterates over the matrix. I got the idea from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4213674/8427463

Example: extract all 'r' in rownames(mtcar) and concatenate as a vector

```
library(stringr)
apply(str_extract_all(rownames(mtcars),"r",simplify = TRUE),1,paste,collapse="")
```

Comment: If you share a piece of your data we could help you in a more efficient way.