# Extract all matches to a new column using regex in R

Tags: r, regex, stringr, dplyr

In my data, I have a column of open text field data that resembles the following sample:

```
d <- tribble(
  ~x,
  "i am 10 and she is 50",
  "he is 32 and i am 22",
  "he may be 70 and she may be 99",
)
```

I would like to use `regex` to extract all two digit numbers to a new column called `y`. I have the following code and it works well extracting the first match:

```
d %>%
  mutate(y = str_extract(x, "([0-9]{2})"))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  x                              y    
  <chr>                          <chr>
1 i am 10 and she is 50          10   
2 he is 32 and i am 22           32   
3 he may be 70 and she may be 99 70
```

But, is there a way to extract both two-digit numbers to the same column with some standard separator (e.g comma)?

Comment: This post should help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57059625/5325862. To clarify, you *only* want to extract two-digit numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `str_extract_all` instead of `str_extract` because `str_extract` matches only the first instance where as the `_all` suffix is global and would extract all the instances in a `list`, which can be convert back to two columns with `unnest_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
d %>%  
    mutate(out =  str_extract_all(x, "\\d{2}")) %>% 
    unnest_wider(c(out)) %>%
    rename_at(-1, ~ c('y', 'z')) %>%
    type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# x                                  y     z
#  <chr>                          <int> <int>
#1 i am 10 and she is 50             10    50
#2 he is 32 and i am 22              32    22
#3 he may be 70 and she may be 99    70    99
```

---

If we need as a string column with `,` as separator, after extraction into a `list`, loop over the `list` with `map` and concatenate all elements to a single string with `toString` (wrapper for `paste(., collapse=", ")`)

```
library(purrr)
d %>%
   mutate(y = str_extract_all(x, "\\b\\d{2}\\b") %>%
                 map_chr(toString))
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  x                              y     
#  <chr>                          <chr> 
#1 i am 10 and she is 50          10, 50
#2 he is 32 and i am 22           32, 22
#3 he may be 70 and she may be 99 70, 99
```

Comment: I just tried your code and it says that the function "unnest_wider" could not be found.

Answer (score 4):

We can also use `extract` and `unite` from `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d %>%
  extract(x, c('y', 'z'), regex = "(\\d+)[^\\d]+(\\d+)", remove = FALSE)
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  x                              y     z    
  <chr>                          <chr> <chr>
1 i am 10 and she is 50          10    50   
2 he is 32 and i am 22           32    22   
3 he may be 70 and she may be 99 70    99
```

Return single column:

```
d %>%
  extract(x, c('y', 'z'), regex = "(\\d+)[^\\d]+(\\d+)", remove = FALSE) %>%
  unite('y', y, z, sep = ', ')
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  x                              y     
  <chr>                          <chr> 
1 i am 10 and she is 50          10, 50
2 he is 32 and i am 22           32, 22
3 he may be 70 and she may be 99 70, 99
```