# Convert output of str_extract_all to vector of numeric entries instead of list

Tags: r, dataframe, list, dplyr, stringr

I use `str_extract_all()` from the `stringr` package to extract all numbers from strings. The dataset I am using is

```
dat <- data.frame(
  X1 = rep(
    c(
      "DIESEL", "", "Oberösterreich", "", "Salzburg", "", "Steiermark",
      ""
    ),
    c(1L, 10L, 1L, 15L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 6L)
  ),
  X2 = c(
    "Mistelbach Bezirk", "", "Mödling", "Neunkirchen", "Sankt Pölten(Land)",
    "Scheibbs", "Tulln", "Waidhofen an der Thaya", "Wiener Neustadt(Land)",
    "Wien-Umgebung", "Zwettl", "Linz(Stadt)", "Steyr(Land / Stadt)",
    "Wels(Stadt / Land)", "Braunau am Inn", "Eferding", "Freistadt",
    "Gmunden", "Grieskirchen", "Kirchdorf an der Krems", "Linz-Land",
    "Perg", "Ried im Innkreis", "Rohrbach", "Schärding", "Urfahr-Umgebung",
    "Vöcklabruck", "Salzburg(Stadt)", "Hallein", "Salzburg-Umgebung",
    "Sankt Johann im Pongau", "Tamsweg", "Zell am See", "Graz(Stadt)",
    "Bruck an der Mur", "Deutschlandsberg", "Feldbach", "Fürstenfeld",
    "Graz-Umgebung", ""
  ),
  X3 = rep("", 40L),
  X4 = c(
    "Tank- 33", "", "stellen 30", "22", "36", "11", "31", "13",
    "24", "46", "35", "38", "33", "51", "41", "18", "33", "38", "34",
    "21", "39", "24", "34", "25", "36", "40", "50", "32", "17", "52",
    "36", "9", "38", "55", "22", "24", "37", "18", "80", ""
  ),
  X5 = c(
    "Änderun6g.e2n98", "", "(Häufig1k0e.i6t2) 1", "2.834", "8.342",
    "869", "3.636", "399", "5.684", "13.599", "4.661", "15.855",
    "11.094", "19.068", "5.344", "5.143", "4.133", "11.363", "3.064",
    "8.020", "15.607", "4.988", "9.854", "741", "5.144", "9.515",
    "11.973", "12.056", "4.913", "16.722", "9.015", "446", "8.888",
    "16.007", "5.175", "4.507", "6.796", "1.460", "20.271", ""
  ),
  X6 = c(
    "190,85", "Häufigkeit", "354,03", "128,82", "231,72", "79,00",
    "117,29", "30,69", "236,83", "295,63", "133,17", "417,24", "336,18",
    "373,88", "130,34", "285,72", "125,24", "299,03", "90,12", "381,90",
    "400,18", "207,83", "289,82", "29,64", "142,89", "237,88", "239,46",
    "376,75", "289,00", "321,58", "250,42", "49,56", "233,89", "291,04",
    "235,23", "187,79", "183,68", "81,11", "253,39", ""
  ),
  X7 = c(
    "1,205", "", "1,205", "1,249", "1,199", "1,230", "1,240", "1,181",
    "1,198", "1,219", "1,190", "1,193", "1,197", "1,192", "1,237",
    "1,163", "1,208", "1,203", "1,176", "1,196", "1,184", "1,172",
    "1,186", "1,201", "1,215", "1,195", "1,204", "1,228", "1,231",
    "1,226", "1,243", "1,318", "1,246", "1,204", "1,215", "1,208",
    "1,174", "1,232", "1,209", ""
  ),
  X8 = c(
    "1,173", "", "1,173", "1,209", "1,197", "1,229", "1,189", "1,174",
    "1,181", "1,189", "1,171", "1,170", "1,181", "1,175", "1,199",
    "1,153", "1,188", "1,184", "1,169", "1,181", "1,169", "1,168",
    "1,177", "1,194", "1,191", "1,176", "1,179", "1,200", "1,209",
    "1,194", "1,199", "1,309", "1,218", "1,172", "1,183", "1,169",
    "1,161", "1,232", "1,179", ""
  ),
  X9 = c(
    "1,157", "", "1,158", "1,192", "1,180", "1,209", "1,169", "1,159",
    "1,164", "1,173", "1,162", "1,155", "1,168", "1,163", "1,179",
    "1,141", "1,174", "1,164", "1,159", "1,167", "1,154", "1,154",
    "1,164", "1,184", "1,177", "1,163", "1,159", "1,189", "1,194",
    "1,179", "1,184", "1,289", "1,198", "1,153", "1,161", "1,149",
    "1,146", "1,199", "1,159", ""
  ),
  X10 = c(
    "1,207", "", "1,195", "1,239", "1,214", "1,249", "1,219", "1,209",
    "1,199", "1,209", "1,182", "1,189", "1,199", "1,189", "1,219",
    "1,164", "1,199", "1,204", "1,189", "1,198", "1,189", "1,185",
    "1,194", "1,209", "1,209", "1,193", "1,199", "1,224", "1,229",
    "1,218", "1,239", "1,339", "1,239", "1,199", "1,199", "1,186",
    "1,184", "1,259", "1,199", ""
  ),
  X11 = c(
    "0,050", "", "0,037", "0,047", "0,034", "0,040", "0,050", "0,050",
    "0,035", "0,036", "0,020", "0,034", "0,031", "0,026", "0,040",
    "0,023", "0,025", "0,040", "0,030", "0,031", "0,035", "0,031",
    "0,030", "0,025", "0,032", "0,030", "0,040", "0,035", "0,035",
    "0,039", "0,055", "0,050", "0,041", "0,046", "0,038", "0,037",
    "0,038", "0,060", "0,040", ""
  ),
  X12 = c(
    "4,32%", "", "3,20%", "3,94%", "2,88%", "3,31%", "4,28%", "4,31%",
    "3,01%", "3,07%", "1,72%", "2,94%", "2,65%", "2,24%", "3,39%",
    "2,02%", "2,13%", "3,44%", "2,59%", "2,66%", "3,03%", "2,69%",
    "2,58%", "2,11%", "2,72%", "2,58%", "3,45%", "2,94%", "2,93%",
    "3,31%", "4,65%", "3,88%", "3,42%", "3,99%", "3,27%", "3,22%",
    "3,32%", "5,00%", "3,45%", "27 / 32"
  )
)
```

Then, I apply the following code to clean the dataset `dat`

```
library(dplyr)
library(string)

dat = dat %>% select(-X3) %>%
             slice(-2) %>%
             mutate(X1 = '',
                    X2 = str_remove(X2, ' Bezirk'),
                    X4 = str_remove(X4, 'Tank- '),
                    X4 = str_remove(X4, 'stellen '),
                    X5 = str_extract_all(X5, '[:digit:]'))
```

and now the problem occurs. The function `str_extract_all()` returns a list of the extracted numbers separated by commas, and the list is stored in column `X5`. So, I have a list of lists now. My objective is a column `X5` consisting of numeric entries which I can further work with such as

```
X5
6298
10621
...
```

I tried many different ways and am out of ideas for now. Could anyone help me out how to achieve this?

As a side note: I apply the code to many lists of the same structure using `lapply()`.

I am thankful for any hints!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [str\_extract\_all: return all patterns found in string concatenated as vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57059625/str-extract-all-return-all-patterns-found-in-string-concatenated-as-vector)

Comment: `X5` already has numbers. Why do you need to extract numbers from a number? You will end up getting the digits. Probably you just need `as.numeric(X5)` or even `parse_number(X5)` etc but not `str_extract_all`

Comment: @Onyambu as you can see X5 consists mostly of numbers, but the first three rows are mixed (characters and numbers), so in order to extract the numbers I use `str_extract_all()`. Also, `as.numeric(X5)` after extracting the numbers does not work.

Comment: Then deal with those three separately. Do not use str_extract. You rather use str_replace

Comment: Also, `parse_number()` only returns the first number found. However, I need to extract all numbers, as my MWE shows. Dealing with those three separately does not solve the problem at all. It `str_extract_all()` still returns, as described, a list which I cannot continue working with. Also, the first three rows differ between my lists I have to edit, so manually specifying it is also not a solution. I mentioned in my post that I have to apply my code to many lists.

Comment: In order to allow for further answers, what do I need to clarify in the post? As far as I can tell it is not missing any important information! So, either remove the requirement, or let me know what is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dat |> mutate(X5 = purrr::map_chr(X5, paste0, collapse = ""))`

Comment: In combination with `as.numeric()`, so `as.numeric(mutate(X5 = purrr::map_chr(X5, paste0, collapse = "")))`, it is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you @Marcus!